# Problema con GitHub y proyecto subido

Tags: javascript, html, css, git, github

Hola chicos buenas tardes vuelvo a molestar, estuve subiendo mi proyecto a github pero me surge un problema en el tema de las imagenes, estan todas subidas revise bien el repositorio pero no las toma una seccion en especifico " https://leonania.github.io/LRDM/Javascript%20NANIA%20FINAL%20-%20copia/indexcarrito.html ".

Lo que me parece raro es que con el proyecto ejecutado desde el VSC anda perfecto y corre todas las imagenes.

Aca les dejo el link del repo https://github.com/leonania/LRDM .

Comment: solo a titulo informativo: estas utilizando Git, que es un gestor de control de versiones. No hace falta ir cambiando nombres e ir añadiendo "Final" "este SI", "ahora corregido"... esto lo vas haciendo en cada commit, y los archivos pueden mantener nombres mas coherentes. (te lo comento por el nombre de la carpeta "Javscript NANIA final"

Answer (score 2):

Voy a demostrarte cuál es el problema con el caso de la imagen de la tartafruta, el directorio en el cuál está la imagen de la tartafruta es:

```
LRDM/Images/platos
```

Y el directorio donde está tu archivo principal de html es:

```
LRDM/Javascript%20NANIA%20FINAL%20-%20copia/indexcarrito.html
```

En ese HTML defines tu imagen como un HTML de la siguiente manera:

```
<img class="item-image" src="Images/platos/tartafruta.jpg">
```

Esto es un `path` relativo y por lo tanto está tratando de buscar la carpeta `"Images"` dentro de la carpeta `"Javascript NANIA FINAL"` y no la encuentra, debido a que está fuera de esta carpeta. Una solución sería subir hasta el directorio principal y buscar la imagen en la carpeta correspondiente, así:

```
<img class="item-image" src="../Images/platos/tartafruta.jpg">
```

Con `../` le estas diciendo a tu explorador web que busque la imagen una carpeta afuera de donde está el `.html` (en la carpeta `"LRDM"`) y que en esa carpeta busque la carpeta "Images". Otra solución si no quieres cambiar tu código sería meter la carpeta de "Images" donde está tu `.html` principal.